# django add style sheet to site

Tags: css, django

Learning how to add style sheet to django site.  Have added the code I think I need, but the site completely ignores it.  Here are my files;

urls.py

```
import os.path
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from users.views import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

stylesheets = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'stylesheets')

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  (r'^$', main_page),
  (r'^stylesheets/(?P<path>.*)$',
    'django.views.static.serve',
    { 'document_root': stylesheets }),
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'chapter6.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^chapter6/', include('chapter6.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

The main_page.html file

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>The users application</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="/var/chapter6/stylesheets/style.css"
    type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>The users application</h1>
    Here are the users:
    <p>{{ username1 }} </p>
    <p>{{ username2 }} </p>
    <p>{{ username3 }} </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Lastly, here is the style sheet.

```
body {
  font-size: 12pt;
  background-color: pink;
}

h1 {
  color: red;
}


p {
  font-size: 20pt;
}
```

I have gone over all the code a dozen time and can't find anything wrong.  I am learning django from the book "django: visual quick pro guide".  All the code looks right by the book.  I have found a few errors in the book though.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Bobby

Comment: Can you post a link to your page?

Comment: Can you post your settings.py?

Answer (score 1):

Your URLconf maps '/stylesheets/' but your HTML is looking at '/var/chapter6/stylesheets'.

Comment: I tried it both ways.  It didn't help.  I am glad to know how to verify the relationship though.  I put it back to match, but it still does not work.

Comment: please edit your question to show what your live code now looks like. the link should be <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 0):

That book was published in 2009 (and doesn't have very good reviews, anyways). A *lot* has changed in Django since 2009, so I would look for another starting place, if I were you. Unfortunately, though, there's no many in-print Django books that are much more up-to-date.

The best place to start, though, id the [online Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/). It's the same as the in-print *Definitive Guide to Django* but is constantly updated online as Django itself changes.

That said, I'm assuming if you're just starting that you're using the latest version of Django (1.4 at the time). If not, upgrade immediately. In Django 1.3+, handling static files is trivial, and requires just the following settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Add `django.contrib.staticfiles` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and you *may* need to add the following lines to your `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

In development, Django will then serve anything in each app's `static` directory under `STATIC_URL`. If you need project-wide resources, put them in another directory, such as "assets", and then add that directory to `STATICFILES_DIRS`:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'assets'),
)
```

When you go to production, `STATIC_ROOT` and `MEDIA_ROOT` will be served by your webserver instead of Django. For the purposes of static files, you'll need to run:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

To have Django copy everything into `STATIC_ROOT`. This is only for production. This directory should not even exist in development.

See also:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

Comment: Is the Django book really "constantly updated"? I don't see any evidence of that. The only thing that's constantly updated is the documentation itself.

Comment: Huh, well, I guess not. Honestly, I don't use it, since it long lost usefulness for me. In fact, I find if I actually don't understand how something works, now, I have to go straight to the source more than even the documentation. It was my assumption that it was a living document, and that there was still effort being made to keep it up-to-date. Seems that that is sadly not the case and it looks to be all but abandoned at this point. Sorry.

Comment: On a somewhat unrelated note, Django has a very vibrant community, but it seems none of us cares for the art of writing much, or perhaps we're all just too busy coding to write anything (yeah, that's better). There's very few blogs, very few books, very few screencasts, etc. It's pretty much just the docs, and then going straight to the community on sites like this or in IRC, message boards, etc.

Comment: I added the text in the various spots you suggested, but I still was not getting results.  I tried a different test to see if maybe I was not successfully resolving the directory name for the stylesheets directory.  This is what my code said;  stylesheets = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'stylesheets').  I then changed it to this;  stylesheets = 'var/chapter6/stylesheets'.  That worked so I know the problem is with the first version.  I just can't find anything wrong with it.

Comment: Are you using Django 1.4? The default project layout in that version is a little different than in every other version. The code you have assumes that the "stylesheets" directory is on the same level as settings.py. If that's not the case, then you need to modify your code to traverse into the right directory.